# When stack stores data in LIFO

Tags: c, stack-memory

Typically the stack grows downward, meaning that items deeper in the call chain are at numerically lower addresses.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
        unsigned int a[10];
        printf("%x \n",&a[0]);
        printf("%x \n",&a[1]);
        return 0;
}


/*--------- output is ---*/
4bd813d0 
4bd813d4 
/*--------- output is ---*/
```

Question: The address should be grow from high to low ?  can someone help me understand this..

Comment: Stack grows downwards but it does not mean the arrays are stored like that. When a new var needs to be allocated on the stack the stack grows down by the size of the variable but the variable start is placed at the lowest address not the highest address.

Comment: `%p` is proper for outputting pointers, e.g. `printf("%p\n", (void*)&a[0]);` (**note:** do NOT add a space between `%p` and `'\n'`)

Comment: "Typically" is important. There are real-world systems with a stack growing upwards.

Answer (score 1):

For showing that the stack grows downwards you need something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void Bar(int a)
{
  volatile int local = a;
  printf("Bar: %p\n", (void*)&a);
}

void Foo(int a)
{
  volatile int local = a;
  printf("Foo: %p\n", (void*)&a);
  Bar(a);
}

int main()
{
  Foo(1);
}
```

Here the functions `Foo` and `Bar` print the address of a local variable. As local variables are usually stored on the stack.

`Bar` which is called from `Foo` will print a lower address that `Foo`.

Possible output:

```
Foo: 00000043321AFB80
Bar: 00000043321AFA60
```

Be aware that C does not necesssarily use a stack as the usage of a stack is not covered by the C standard. But the majority of C implementations do use a stack.

Answer (score -2):

In C here, you are creating an array of integers. Regardless of the data structure that you thought of (a stack), the addresses of the elements in an array in C are adjacent to each other.

Since this is an array of integers and each integer takes up 4 bytes of space, the address of each element increases by 4.

This might help you: [Youtube Video on Implementing a Stack in C](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sFVxsglODoo)

Comment: OP is not asking about general stack data structures but rather the process/call stack.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.